# Moving Story Ending: 결말 or 엔딩

Tags: vocabulary, translation, meaning, word-choice

When referring to the "End of a movie or story",  should I use 결말 or 엔딩 . I can't telling using Papago or Google translate. Also, how to refer to Beginning of Movie? Is it 시작?

Comment: 엔딩 is just an English word written in Korean letters. Are you asking if this is understandable?

Answer (score 2):

결말 (end, resolution) is a widely used word referring to stories or  real life matters.  엔딩 is hardly used except in some common phrases like 해피 엔딩 (or 해피엔드).

Here are words for "beginning" and "end".

- 시작 <-> 끝.  Most common terms for "beginning" and "end(ing)".
- 출발 <-> 결말. These have implications on the state of things, like commencement and resolution.
- 처음 <-> 마지막.  These focus more on the point in time, like "start point" and "the last" of something.

For a movie or story, you could also add 부분 (part). 부분 is used rather frequently in Korean.

So you can say things like:

- 끝에 / 끝 부분에 / 결말에 반전이 있는 영화 = a movies with a twist at the end.
- 영화가 시작은 (or 출발은 / 처음엔) 좋았는데 끝 부분에 (마지막에) 가서는 지루하더라 = The movies started well but it got boring toward the end.